# Terminal for tfdbg on windows 10

Tags: tensorflow, console

In tutorial i see that on linux tfdbg have menu and interact with mouse clicks. That doesn't work in windows 10. Is there terminal for windows (or other solution) for work with all tfdbg features (menu, mouse)?
My tensorflow version is 1.3.0

Comment: The mouse mode of tfdbg you refer to depends on the Python curses library. Unfortunately, there is no easy way to get curses working on Windows AFAIK .This is the reason why tfdbg uses readline (pyreadline in Python), which doesn't have mouse support, on Windows by default.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.
That's pity, that I cannot enable curses for tfdbg (using unicurses for example) without rewriting it.